# read_dir() function is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to zip a folder(client1) which contains few pdf file and after that zip folder should download.
Path is correct but fail to made a zip file.

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks In Advance

I made following code:

```
 function download_all_pdf(){
$this->load->library('Zip');
$path = base_url().'public/pdfstore/client1';
$this->zip->read_dir($path);
   $this->zip->download('client1.zip');
}
```

Comment: You path should not be absolute path, it should be relative path, refer the doc here ---> http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use http:// path. Yu have to use local address. So something like this

```
$path = 'public/pdfstore/clint1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function download_all_pdf(){
    $this->load->library('zip');
    $path = './public/pdfstore/client1';
    $this->zip->read_dir($path);
    $this->zip->download('client1.zip');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`base_url()` returns an **HTTP URL**, but you need a **local path**.
A good choice is to use a local path that is portable. Achieve it by using constant `APPPATH`. Illustrated as below:

```
function download_my_zip_files(){
    $this->load->library('zip');            
    $basePath = APPPATH."/path/to/your/dir/";
    $this->zip->read_dir($basePath);
    $this->zip->download('my_zip_file.zip');
}
```